# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject

Tags: android, proguard, rx-java2

I have created a library project using Rxjava2 and other libraries. 
I have generated the aar file using proguard on.

while using the library in my sample app I am getting crash

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject;
    at b.a.a.d.d.<init>(Unknown Source:3)
    at b.a.a.d.d.a(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.sample.MySDK.init(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.sample.MainActivity.initializeSDK(MainActivity.java:105)
    at com.sample.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:31)
    at com.sample.MainAhere`ctivity$3.onResponse(MainActivity.java:92)
```

Comment: With which gradle keyword do you include the RxJava2 in you library? Compile, api or implementation?

Take a look here also https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation

Comment: I tried with both api and implementation

Comment: Hello, I got the same problem. How did you solve? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your library is using `implementation` to pull in the RxJava dependencies. A library usually uses `api` for such dependencies, so apps using the library pull in RxJava via transitive dependencies.

Comment: Yes I m using implementation  to pull in the RxJava dependencies.

now I changed to
api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9'
api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'

still getting the same error

Comment: @BalaramNayak: Make sure that you are publishing your AAR in a repository, whether a public one (e.g., Maven Central, JCenter) or a private one (e.g., `mavenLocal()`). If you do not want to do that, and you want to force users of your library to manually handle AAR files, then they will also need to add in the RxJava dependencies themselves.